# Call Javascript function with two different context

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say I have a `function` in a `namespace` like:

```
app.MyNamespace = {
    defaults: {
        myOption: 1
    },
    myFunction(param1, param2, options){
         options = $.extend(options, this.defaults);
    }
}
```

then if I call this in some other context (e.g. `window`) with

```
app.MyNamespace.myFunction.call(this);
```

obviusly the `options` does not extend with the `defaults` because it loose the right context.

How can I mantain the `defaults` in the function, but calling it in another context?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fxruLka5)

Comment: `app.MyNamespace.myFunction.call(this);` why would you call it like that?

Comment: because it can be used by different classes, it's kinda of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern

Comment: you can use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) In your `myFunction` you add `.bind(this);`

Comment: maybe you did not get my point :)

Comment: Oh ok.. so you want to change the context. Thought the problem was maintain the context.

Answer (score 2):

just point it to defaults

```
app.MyNamespace = {
    defaults: {
        myOption: 1
    },
    myFunction(param1, param2, options){
         options = $.extend(options, app.MyNamespace.defaults);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if i get what you want, this should do:

```
app.MyNamespace = {
defaults: {
    myOption: 1
},
myFunction:function(param1, param2, options, scope){
     options = $.extend(options, this.defaults);
 }}; app.MyNamespace.myFunction('param1','param2', {option1:1,option2:2}, this);
```